# TV cartoon show with a young guy that sometimes goes into the past and becomes an Egyptian god

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I think he was a young guy who would usually go to this Egyptian museum, and I guess he used to talk to a historical researcher. Somehow he kind of goes into the past and becomes Ra (god of the sun), and they fight some other gods. Back then Egypt was really civilized, and it had great technology.

Comment: Welcome to SFF, this is a good overview of the show! Can you remember anything else though? When did you watch this? How old would the show be? Can you remember what any of the characters looked like? Any specific episode plots? How do they go back in time? Does someone else go back as well? Can you expand on Egypt's technology levels? If you want to change anything or add something else that you remember please [edit] it into the question. You may also want to take the [tour] to learn a little more about the site!

Answer (score 7):

[*Egyxos*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4332766/)

[image: Cover image for Egyxos]

> An ancient civilization lost in time and space, is coming back - the
> Egyxos. They are incredible creatures gifted with superpowers split
> into two factions endlessly battling for the domination over their
> kingdom. During the fighting between the two warrior brothers Kefer
> and Exaton, the earthly boy Leo is involved despite his will. He
> doesn't know he has inherited a great power - The last Pharaoh's one.
> Once Leo finds out his gift, his life will change forever and a big
> adventure between two worlds, where danger is always lurking, will
> begin.

### Trailer

Comment: thank you that was what I was looking for